# not able to modify last <li> with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have some nested `<UL><li><ul><li>text</li></ul></li></UL>`, I want to modify last child using jquery, but when I am writing $("#id li:last-child") it affecting all nested `<li>`s. here is the code.

```
<ul id="ddmenu">
<li><a href="#">Home></a>
    <ul>        

          <li><a href="#">QA Managers Dashboard</a></li>    
    </ul> 
 </li>

<li><a href="#">Req Mgmt</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Panel Beating</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Car Inspection</a></li>
    </ul>

</li>
<li><a href="#">Test</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Work Place</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Special Events</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Project</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Enquiry</a></li>        
    </ul>
</li>
   <li><a href="#">More</a></li>
```

I want to modify the `<li>` which contains text "More"... how to do that?? any help please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `>` to get only direct descendants like this

```
$("#id > li:last-child")
```

Comment: @UsabilityStudio, please don't forget to accept the answer if it was helpful. It will prevent other people from trying to find another solution.

Answer (score 0):

I you know how much items you have, you can try `$("#id li:nth-child("+nbrItems+")");`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below code,

```
$("#id > li:last-child")
```

the symbol ">" represents direct children of the parent element.

Answer (score 0):

Just as out of general interest (and I accept that your problem's already solved) but the following *also* works:

```
$('li:last-child:last').css('color','red');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/6SJsq/).

I understand *why* it works this way, but I must confess that when I first wrote that selector I expected that `$('li:last-child:first')` would work.